# How to read character from file c++

Tags: c++, file, char

Is there something like fgetc in c++? File contains 3 words "send more money" and I need to solve a task where each letter represents a number(money is the answer(:D) and I add send+more), thats why I want to read each string as char array, but now I'm struggling to do so, the only info that I got is how to read everything between spaces. So, is there something like fgetc was in c or should I rethink how to do this task?
(sorry if I will be slow to respond have to go to sleep)

Comment: you mean other than `fgetc`????

Comment: Do you mean `istream::get()`?

Comment: You want iostreams and cstdio and stdio.h

Comment: File I/O questions and answers are abundant on SO, I'm sure there are plenty which already answer your question.

Comment: Wait, does fgetc work in c++, cause while looking for it I noticed that the only examples of it are written in c and this really got me mixed up http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgetc/

Comment: go get your sleep man

Comment: An often quoted reason for c++'s success is that you can use c libraries with it. This of course includes the C standard library.

Comment: You could use `std::istream::read` function to read one character at a time or `std::getline` to read a line at a time, which is usually more efficient.

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iolibrary/ <- VERY USEFUL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's always `std::istream::get()`, which works exactly like
`fgetc`.  More idiomatic in C++ might be to use
`std::istream::get(char&)`, which stores the results directly
into a `char` (rather than returning an `int`, which must be
checked for `EOF` *before* converting it to a `char`), and
signals end of file or an error in the usual way.

Answer (score 0):

istream/fstream have a get function that will return characters

Comment: No it doesn't.  There are several `std::istream::get` functions, but none return a `char`.